# Write True if the value to the left is "Home"

Tags: vba, excel

I need a macro that paste true in column B if the value to the left is "home" and false if is not. I was trying to use If and Else staments but I cannot figure out how to create a code when my values are letters.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you get an answer sooner. Remember, this isn't a code-writing service, so post what you've tried & we can help you fix it.

Comment: Can you not use a formula?

Comment: Does this need to be in code? A formula would seem like an easier approach.

Comment: I need a formula. Sorry for not uploading my code. I just started learning VBA :(

Answer (score 1):

This should work but it's untested:

```
Sub CheckColumn()
Dim maxrow As Integer, i As Integer

With ActiveSheet
    maxrow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For i = 1 To maxrow
        If .Cells(i, 1) = "home" Then
            .Cells(i, 2) = "true"
        Else
            .Cells(i, 2) = "false"
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Again... formula approach would be much easier.

Comment: Thank you rohrl77.  The program shows an error  it says "Compile error: Next without For." I have several random names in column A up to A10 and in column B, I have to paste True if the value to the left is "Home" and false if is not.  I am using VBA because I need practice with the program.

Comment: ooops... my bad. I missed one `End If`. See correction above